# dojo/aspect's before()/after() once()?

Tags: javascript, dojo, aspect

dojo/on has once() which is extremely useful. How to implement such behaviour in dojo/aspect's before()/after()? I can't believe somebody implemented once() to dojo/on but not dojo/aspect. I don't see any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is it so difficult to save the return of before/after and call `remove` on it? Here's a simple implementation :

```
aspect.onceAfter: function(target, methodName, advice, receiveArguments){
  var handle = aspect.after(target, methodName, function(){
    handle.remove();
    advice.apply(null, arguments);
  }, receiveArguments);
}
```

Comment: It's not difficult but I'm wondering why such inconsistencies in the API. It would take minutes to implement something like this into the aspect module. Now I have to change 100 references in my applications from dojo/aspect to my/new/aspect which includes this functionality.

Comment: I can't speak for the motivation of whoever wrote the dojo APIs, but I know I've never had a need for this `once` function with after/before, I'm curious to know your use case to be honest. Also, thanks for spotting the typo =)

Comment: Neither have I and I have written probably ~ 50k lines of code with Dojo in numerous apps. And this is the first time I need it because it just seems so handy. It's a great automatic thing when modules are independent/loosely coupled - once() and you're done and the rest is GC :)

Comment: I suppose that's because it isn't a concept that is used in aspect oriented programming. AOP is about cross cutting concerns and "injecting" code at multiple points in your program (things like logging).
It's purpose is not to execute a block of code once and then never again. I've never seen any aspect oriented code that should be executed once. With this mindset you wouldn't think of creating a "once" feature.

Comment: You can submit a feature request on bugtrac. It will most likely get accepted.